# AWS set up DNS with load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, load-balancing

I have an aws ec2 cluster and an application load balancer, the cluster runs a service which uses the load balancer.

I can access the load balancer through https using the load balancer's dns name (with a certificate error of course).

Now I want to direct my DNS server (managed through namecheap.com) to the load balancer. For that I need to add an A record with the static IP of the load balancer. I understand there is no static IPs for load balancers in AWS.

So does anyone know how I can do that? I am migrating my project from google cloud and I'm new to AWS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AWS ELB/ALB doesn't provide static IP address, the IP addresses can change and can add up and removed if the traffic scales up or down.
You need to create a CNAME for your domain to ELB DNS name.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-elb-load-balancer.html

However, you can't have CNAME for the apex domain , if you have the option in Nemacheap, it's good, otherwise Route53 Alias record is an option.

Comment: And the ELB DNS is static?